# XMLRPC::DateTime Formatting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, parameters, xml-rpc, trac

I'm working on a Rails project that requires using an XMLRPC protocol to access a Trac database.

Everything had been working fine until I needed to make a request with a `XMLRPC::DateTime` parameter. Now when I go to load the page, I get the error message:

```
Wrong content-type (received 'application/xml' but expected 'text/xml')
```

I have tried formatting the date parameter in a bunch of different ways (listed below), but nothing seems to be working.

I've tried:

```
    - @date = Time.now #=> (Tue Jul 10 10:18:01 -0700 2012)
    - @date = DateTime.now #=> (2012-07-10T10:17:37-07:00)
    - @date = Time.now.to_datetime #=> (2012-07-10T10:19:24-07:00)
    - @date = XMLRPC::Convert.dateTime(Time.now.to_datetime.to_s) #=> 
      #<XMLRPC::DateTime:0x1276aa068> 
      (The above hex number changes each time the page is refreshed)
```

Do you know what could be going wrong here?

UPDATE: The code where I make the call is pasted below (I'm using the trac4r ruby gem to actually make calls to the API):

```
def foo  
   date = DateTime.now.to_s  
   tickets = trac.tickets.query(:max => 1000, :created_at => date)  
   return tickets.size  
end
```

Comment: The `0x1276aa068` is just that `XMLRPC::DateTime` class instance's direct hexidecimal value. Every new instance *(even with the same attributes passed)* will have a different identifying value.

Comment: Thanks - I understand that now. But do you know why I would be getting this content-type error when passing @date as a parameter?

Comment: I believe `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss` format is correct for a DateTime in XML. Have you tried `DateTime.now.to_s` *(getting the String instead of the DateTime object)*?

Comment: Yep - it still gives you the same problem! I'll keep searching for the moment...

Comment: Can you post code where `@date` is actually used?

Comment: Updated in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem you're using hasn't been updated in more than 2 years. I mention this because with age like that it is possible that some features of the gem no longer work due to changes that may have occurred in Ruby's XMLRPC since *(I will have to dig more to find proof of this)*.

What I don't like is this [`args_to_trac_args`](https://github.com/csexton/trac4r/blob/master/lib/trac4r/tickets.rb#L171) method.

```
> args_to_trac_args({:max => 1000, :created_at => DateTime.now.to_s})
  => "max=1000&created_at=2012-07-10T13:58:13-04:00"
```

This string is then passed to an `XMLRPC::Client` instance's [`call`](https://github.com/csexton/trac4r/blob/master/lib/trac4r/query.rb#L51) method.

In the `XMLRPC::Client`'s `call` method, the above string is passed to [`methodCall`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/xmlrpc/rdoc/XMLRPC/Create.html#method-i-methodCall) in `XMLRPC::Create`. If you view the source of that method, you'll see it tries to generate valid XML elements for each parameter passed.

```
parameter = params.collect do |param|
    @writer.ele("param", conv2value(param))
end
```

This is generating a single `<param>` element like

```
<param>
  <value>
    <string>max=1000&amp;created_at=2012-07-10T13:58:13-04:00</string>
  </value>
</param>
```

If I generate a full document by hand using the `"max=1000&created_at=2012-07-10T13:58:13-04:00"` string as the gem will

```
require "xmlrpc/client"

writer = XMLRPC::Create.new
writer.methodCall('ticket.query', "max=1000&created_at=2012-07-10T13:58:13-04:00")
```

the XML generated is **invalid** due to the `&created_at=...`

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>ticket.query</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>max=1000&amp;created_at=2012-07-10T13:58:13-04:00</string>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

To me it seems the intended response is something more like

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<methodCall>
    <methodName>ticket.query</methodName>
    <params>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>max=1000</string>
            </value>
        </param>
        <param>
            <value>
                <string>created_at=2012-07-10T13:58:13-04:00</string>
            </value>
        </param>
    </params>
</methodCall>
```

but I don't know enough about what Trac is expecting as request paramaters, or how the gem was intending for Ruby's XMLRPC client to work 2+ years ago.

I would verify the expected request format *(one XML `<param>` containing a querystring of arguments, or multiple `<param>` elements)*, fork the Github repo, and make the necessary changes to `args_to_trac_args` *(to me that seems to be the source of the problem)*.

If the params are not joined into a single string and left as an array like `["max=1000", "created_at=2012-08-10T13:58:13-04:00"],`methodCall` will generate the valid XML in the 2nd document shown above

```
writer = XMLRPC::Create.new
writer.methodCall('ticket.query', "max=1000", "created_at=2012-07-10T13:58:13-04:00")
```

Comment: That's brilliant - thanks so much! I'll give it a shot and come back with the results.

Comment: Just letting you know - that was the problem. I cloned and modified the gem for my own app and everything works well now. Thanks again!

Comment: Great! You can accept my answer to your question if it solved your problem. If your repository is public (ie. forked on github) posting a link to that would likely help others too.